# how to make select option value same as name in blades

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

`DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()` returns array of timezones. Values are:

```
[
  0 => "Africa/Abidjan",
  1 => "Africa/Accra",
  2 => "Africa/Addis_Ababa",
  ...
]
```

When I write `{{ Form::select('timezone', DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(), $result->timezone]) }}`  in blade, option value will be 0, 1, 2. I want to make option value equal to name of timezones

Answer (score 1):

Just use [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
Form::select('timezone', array_combine(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(), DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()), $result->timezone])
```